# Just add twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar to your application classpath in net beans and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans-7

I am trying to add a jar in accordance with this link:
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#howToUse It states "Just add twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar to your application classpath."

How do I do that in:

1. Netbeans
2. maven
3. eclipse

Thanks!

Comment: If you are familiar with your favorite IDE you should be able to add this JAR to your project path (for example in Eclipse you right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Built Path and choose the Libraries Tab and add the JAR File). If you create a maven project in your fav IDE add the dependency from your link to the pom.xml and start reading the Twitter4J JavaDoc to getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best answer for netbeans; then I'll use the pom.xml from there:
Daryl Nickerson

> Joined: 23 May 2013
>   Posts: 1
>
> PostPosted: Thu May 23, 2013 4:50 pm    Post subject: Had the same problem, Brian's suggestion worked     Reply with quote
>   Had the same problem, Brian's suggestion worked. (NetbBeans IDE 7.3)
>   To clarify, right-click the Libraries folder in the project viewer, select properties, in Project Properties window, select Libraries, click Add Jar/Folder button, select ALL jar files in your source folder (ctrl-a), not just the folder, and click Open to add them. This may be overkill, but it worked and I was able to compile and run. Thanks, Brian.

Good on Daryl on netbeans news group!

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans and Eclipse it should be right click 'libraries' in the project list, then click add.

This should help with maven http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

For Maven, add the following dependency:

```
  <dependency>           
     <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>           
     <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>           
     <version>3.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: problems, it appears that the twitter.3.0.3 jar I downloaded from http://twitter4j.org/en/versions.html just contains .java files! No class files. Where might I get a the right Jar?

Comment: You can download the latest stable version, which currently is 3.0.5 here: http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download  I see the version 3.0.3 listed on the Maven Central Repository here http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.twitter4j%7Ctwitter4j-core%7C3.0.3%7Cjar